# Naming Conventions - Plurals for Collections

Tags: naming-conventions

I'd like to get some opinion of Naming Conventions for entity collections. In particular I'm designing a RESTful URI structure.

If I have an entity e.g. Account, I would call a collection of such entities Accounts. Similarly: Customer and Customers, Order and Orders. Generally adding an 's' to the end of the entity name. This is a consistent pattern good for a Naming Convention.

But what should I do when some plural words are not simply an 's' tagged on the end e.g. Mouse and Mice, Person and People or even Fish and Fish (plural and singular are the same)?

Should I stick with a simple pattern and just tag on a 's' irrelevant of English Language conventions, or go with the proper pluralised form of a word.

I've been tempted to name my collections e.g. PersonCollection or FishCollection but whilst consistent it is ugly and not the sort of thing I want to enter into URI which I want to be as succinct as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Stick with the English language! It makes the code or the use of interfaces a lot more readable, maintainable and intuitive when somebody with a good understanding of the English language can sit down and work with it. It can be very frustrating to maintain code or interfaces that contain typos in class names, field names, URI parts, ... or other issues like using wrong plural forms as you mentioned. Therefore, I'd never use "Mouses" as the plural form for "Mouse".

Abbreviations might be of concern, too. If it's a known abbreviation, feel free to use it. However, try to keep one strict convention of naming them, like first letter is upper-case the rest lower-case, or all upper-case. Try to avoid mixing those.

Appending the type of the variable or field is like prefixing it. Depending on the programming language in question, I'd go with the general guidelines, e.g. in Java I'd remove the "Collection"-part. As far as URIs are concerned, I wouldn't use it. It doesn't improve readability.